# Graph for a matrix correlation

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjWVa.png)I would like to make a correlation matrix graph of 30 variables. I've used the corrgram R's function, however, the graph is great for a apresentation. Is it possible make another graph using R?

Comment: Have you tried: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/correlation-matrix-a-quick-start-guide-to-analyze-format-and-visualize-a-correlation-matrix-using-r-software

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reference how to make a [great reproducible example in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Share code that you've written so far, consider sharing a sample of your data using `dput()`, and explicitly explain where you've gotten stuck.

Comment: And why you wasn´t happy with your graph?

Comment: Hi! The graph using corrgram got very big. I would like a graph more simple to put in a article.

Comment: can you show your graph to see the starting point?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't kwon how can I put my graph here :(

Comment: @Adriana You can use the instructions here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package `corrplot`. With the help of this package you can create a graphic of correlations.

Comment: Thanks! My data was better with the corrplot.

Answer (score 0):

You can give [levelplot](http://www.r-graph-gallery.com/79-levelplot-with-ggplot2/) a try. You can find other nice plots and their code on this page too.

Comment: Interesting. I will try... Thanks.